# IllegalStateException while configuration change if call DialogFragment in runnable

Tags: java, android

**UPDATE** Problem solved after cancel the timer in onPause()

```
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        new SaveDataDialog().show(getFragmentManager(), "save-data-dialoge");
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 3000);
```

This working nice before configuration change, after IllegalStateException:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: ru.scbit.yarovoe, PID: 21960
              java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
```

Comment: are you doing a fragment commit anywhere and do you cancel the timer properly in lifeycle callbacks?

Comment: Seems like you did not cancel  the timer . Add sufficient code .

Comment: @Raghunandan Thanks you both, I didn't cancel the timer, problem solved!

Comment: @ADM Thanks you both, I didn't cancel the timer, problem solved!